# How to greatly improve privacy against Google apps such as Play Services?

Tags: root-access, google, privacy, lineageos, xprivacy

This is really a long and tiresome journey. So I hope you become my companion!

Device info changed with build.prop and XPrivacy/Lua. Magisk/Xposed in Systemless mode.

I am on my way to achieve finest and most stringent privacy settings possible on android for Google services (Package - Pico). OS is Lineage OS 14.1 - 7.1.2

I am looking to fine tune the privacy settings for Google right now. I have been able to get amazing control over it with the help of XPrivacy/Lua modules of Xposed, but here is the catch. I am not able to get Google Play Store to connect, which is obvious. So I want to know what are the bare minimum permission requirements for it to work while keeping privacy in check?

I have firewalled through AFWall+. Only have allowed Google Play Store and Play Services (Group of apps) to connect.

Steps taken:
Most rights are revoked with the help of Privacy Guard of OS.
System apps are also paralyzed with restrictions.
Most permissions are actually allowed in XPrivacy and Lua.
Critical permissions (Network/Serial/Tracking/Analytics/Location) are denied.
Frozen many Google Apps (and System) with Titanium Backup.
AFWall+ has allowed only limited apps: GApps/Download Manager

After all this, device is stable. No boot loop. No app crash.

Only root apps have true access here. No other app, be it system or user apps, have any easy access to device info.

I am fine tuning each permission as I go. But any input from you can help accelerate this process.

Will you be my north star?

Comment: Please explain *. I am not able to get Google Play Store to connect* what settings in Xprivacy lua did you try? +1

Comment: What exactly are you thinking of restricting?

Comment: Google Play Store stuck at "Checking info..." screen. I have allowed all permissions in XPrivacy except for Serial (Identification) and Network for all Google apps. Lua is restricting tracking and analytics. I have tried bypassing Lua but in vain.

Comment: That is true. But I have setup Lua and XPrivacy in a way that they compliment each other. Lua has many of XPrivacy settings left out. Again, you know me, not an expert. So I am going all in! So basically I have mixed them both. One setting that is missing from Lua is handled by XP and like wise. Also, here's are my paranoid serrings. Any apps first passes through Privacy Guard then XPrivacy Lua and then Xprivacy. Once all checked. Firewall is openend. Could you please provide a link to XDA?

Comment: Neither am an expert. But the expert (developer) says [Since XPrivacyLua is in many aspects better than XPrivacy, running XPrivacy and XPrivacyLua side by side isn't supported](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacyLua/blob/master/FAQ.md) and if you think otherwise, you have to help yourself :-) [Here's the link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=77349010&postcount=596). Sincere suggestion to you is to stick to what's been recommended especially when you don't know how it works

Comment: Honestly, why are using Google apps at all if you already use a Google-free ROM? I'd go with e.g. microG (for location services and GCM if needed), and with F-Droid for apps. If you really need apps from Playstore, use the Yalp Store or Aurora Store apps (available at F-Droid). Much better in terms of privacy – and working fine, I'm using that for years already.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. Do you need help with making Google Services work with the lowest possible permissions or just want to know what else you can do to protect yourself? Also: XPrivacyLua covers everything relevant for privacy, you won't need XPrivacy. If you're missing certain things, you can use a custom hook from the Pro Companion or ask someone to write one for you.

Comment: beeshyams - They might not be compatible. But since I don't have a Pro version of Lua, I am experimenting with both. And it works just fine. I am really careful with them not contradicting each other. Izzy - I know that I should completely remove them. But that's not what I want now right now. I rely on some apps (Office) that requrie Google present. Namnodorel - I want to have minimum permission for Google. Alongside want to have most stringent privacy so I don't leak device info. I will get into details of Pro.

Comment: hello to everyone inside this tread, i am working with my lenovo zuk z2 pro with aosp10 magisk xposed xprivacylua-pro and spending a lots of time in this problem. the last answer is a long time ago and i want to ask each of you for the actual valid (mai2020) solution. @izzy is your post still valid
"microG (for location services and GCM if needed), and with F-Droid for apps. If you really need apps from Playstore, use the Yalp Store or Aurora Store apps" best regards

Comment: @Carsten yes, and I'm still using it that way myself (minus the Play Store access/GCM, which I do not use). And I do not expect that to change within the next 2 years either, before you ask ;)